# Why age field is not rendering in signup page? I have included it in fields in CustomUserCreationForm and Models

Tags: python, django

`

```
    #Code For Custom Forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("age", )

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields


#Code For CustomUser Model

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


#Code For SignUpView

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

#Code Of Signup.html

{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block title%}Sign Up{%endblock title%}
{%block content%}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="post">{%csrf_token%}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
{%endblock content%}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIl9T.png)

You Can see in the image that age field is not showing up for input. things are working completely fine in admin page.The age is showing on the page but not the input for age is showing in signup page.

Comment: Try changing `form_class = UserCreationForm` to `form_class = CustomUserChangeForm`